# Two CSS files loading extremely slow

Tags: css, performance

My WordPress site was running slow so I did a GTMetrix test on it. I have two files that seem to be the problem. How do I locate these files and tackle the issue ?

[image]

Comment: these files has a status of `301` that means there's a redirect when you trying to load them. do you get it loaded at all? my initial guess is that you have an infinite redirection loop when trying to load those files and it simply timeout, eventually.

Comment: No, just removed them,however page is still a bit slow

Comment: You should not only delete files but also stop enqueueing them :)